# Ruby on Rails statement executed on an array check if subelement string is unique

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, where-clause

I have an array objects, for this example lets call it `Diff`. These diffs have multiple fields that are not all the same (`old_image`, `new_image`, `url`, etc). `new_image` and `old_image` in this case have fields on them, most importantly a field called `image_file_name`.

I want to get an array of all the diffs with an unique old_image.image_file_name i.e. no diff should have an old_image with the same file name.

I believe the logic should look something like this.

```
unique_diffs = Array.new
@diff.build.diffs.each { |diff|
    if diff.old_image.image_file_name != @diff.old_image.image_file_name
       unique_diffs.push(diff)
    end
}
```

Or something like this

```
@unique_diffs =  @diff.build.diffs.map{|diff| diff.old_image.image_file_name}.uniq
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the loop, I was hoping to make this cleaner with the uniq function but it didn't seem to work, it gave me back all the diffs instead of the ones with the unique old image filename.

```
@diff.build.diffs.each { |diff|
  if diff.old_image.image_file_name == @diff.old_image.image_file_name
     # Logic went here
  end
}
```

Still open to improving this but for now this will have to do.

Comment: to make uniq to work, just look at the documentation of array.uniq. You find that it use the "eql?" metho of the

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Diff = Struct.new(:old_image)
Image = Struct.new(:image_file_name)

diffs = [
  Diff.new(Image.new('name1')),
  Diff.new(Image.new('name2')),
  Diff.new(nil),
  Diff.new(Image.new('name1')),
]

uniqs =  diffs.select { |diff| diff.old_image }.uniq { |diff| diff.old_image.image_file_name }

p uniqs # prints Diff with name1 and Diff with name 2
```

*The only important line is the one that calls `select` and `uniq`.*

You need to use [`select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-select) to leave only the diffs with the old image, and then use [`uniq`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-uniq) to drop those with the duplicated image file names.

Comment: It gave me all the diffs back, not just the ones with a unique old image filename.